# Method that returns all line numbers a word occurs in a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a method that returns all line numbers a word occurs in a text file.
For example, if "hello" is the parameter, it'll search my text file and return all line numbers "hello" occurs in.

If my test file says:

> Hello
>   my name is
>   is Java.

and my parameter for the method is "my", it should return:

> [2,3]

However, I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Indexer.lineNumbers(Indexer.java:41)
>       at Indexer.main(Indexer.java:22)

Here is my code:

```
public static String lineNumbers(String x) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
            String numbers = "[";
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
            {
               String line = lineReader.readLine();
               if (line.contains(x))
               {
                  int lineNumber = lineReader.getLineNumber();
                  String numberString = Integer.toString(lineNumber);
                  numbers = (numbers + "," + numberString);
               }
            }
            return numbers + "]"; 
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line is line #41 of your code? Whatever object you're accessing in that line is null. Could it possibly be `if(line.contains(x))` ? perhaps `line` is null at some point.

Comment: Also, in you're example, I think you meant for the word to be "is", not "my" :)

Comment: Because the `LineNumberReader` and the `Scanner` are separate objects.  `fileScanner.hasNextLine()` is always true - it won't become false as you read from `lineReader`.  But `readLine()` returns null once `lineReader` reaches the end of the stream.

Comment: Here are some things to think about to make your code more robust: What if the input file contains "hello" and the word you're searching for is "hell"?  What if the input file contains the word "Hello" (capital H) and you're searching for "hello"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to read the same file using a scanner and a line-reader so you end up stepping on your own toes.

Try this:

```
public static String lineNumbers(String x) throws IOException
{
    LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("/Users/alfasi/tpstats-eu-west-1.log"));
    String numbers = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.contains(x))
        {
            numbers += "," + lineReader.getLineNumber();
        }
    }
    return "[" + numbers.substring(1) + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative you may consider puts the line numbers in an ArrayList that you can then iterate over in another process:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> lineNumbers(String x) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ArrayList<Integer> lineNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        lineNumber++;
        if (line.contains(x)) {
            lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
        }
    }
    return lineNumbers;
}
```

Then try looping over the values you get like this:

```
String searchFor = "is";
for(int i : lineNumbers(searchFor)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```